# Don't know how to add up values in database

Tags: c#, database

I have got the input to work but now I need to add to the original number every time I input to the database but I do not know how to do that, any help would be appreciated :)

```
String myConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=E:/coursework/Databases/runner database.accdb;"; // location of the database 
OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection(myConnectionString); // To create the database connection
OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(); // Use the connection for the command
myCommand.Connection = myConnection;

try
{
    myConnection.Open(); // Opens the database connection
    string query = "insert into tblTrainingInformation ([Username],[Calories Burnt]) values('"+GlobalUsername.username+"','" + this.txtCaloriesBurntRun.Text + "')";
    OleDbCommand createCommand = new OleDbCommand(query, myConnection);
    createCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("Your running information has been saved");
    myConnection.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: what failed here, what was the message. Also you need to use command parameters to avoid sql injection.

Comment: What is original number?

Comment: The perfect [Little Bobby Tables](http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/exploits_of_a_mom.png).

Comment: nothing is failing, I have managed to get the input to database working. I need to be able to add to the original inputted number in the database so I can get a total of calories burnt

Comment: What are the data types of your columns and what are the values of `GlobalUsername.username` and `this.txtCaloriesBurntRun.Text` exactly?

Comment: so you need to add a new row for the user if they don't exist and add to their total calories if they do?

Comment: Also before 2-3 days I wrote you full answer how to work with data access layers, you don't implement anything of it here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to UPDATE an existing record adding a new value to your field or INSERT a new record if it is not present you need to know if your database already contains the `Username`.
So you need to run a SELECT query before and then decide if you need an UPDATE or an INSERT
(Access doesn't have some kind of UPSERT statement like MySql or Sql Server)

```
String myConnectionString = ".....";
string querySel = @"SELECT [Username],[Calories Burnt] 
                    FROM tblTrainingInformation 
                    WHERE [Username] = @uname";
using(OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection(myConnectionString))
using(OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(querySel, myConnection))
{
    myConnection.Open(); 
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", GlobalUsername.username);
    using(OleDbDataReader reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader())
    {
        int calories = 0;
        string query = "";
        if(reader.Read())
        {
            // The record exists, read the calories and add the new value
            // then execute the UPDATE 
            calories = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Calories Burnt"]);
            calories += Convert.ToInt32(this.txtCaloriesBurntRun.Text);
            query = @"UPDATE tblTrainingInformation 
                      SET [Calories Burnt] = @cal
                      WHERE [Username] = @uname";
        }
        else
        {
            // Record doesn't exist, INSERT the new data
            calories = Convert.ToInt32(this.txtCaloriesBurntRun.Text);
            query = @"INSERT INTO tblTrainingInformation 
                      ([Calories Burnt],[Username])
                      VALUES(@cal, @uname)";
        }
        reader.Close();
        myCommand.Parameters.Clear();
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cal", calories);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", GlobalUsername.username);
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Your running information has been saved");
    }
}
```

I have made a couple of assumption here.
**First** I assume that `UserName` is the primary key in this table so you can retrieve the record using the WHERE on username value.
**The second** assumption is the type of the field `Calories Burnt`.
It should be a numeric field and, to simplify the example, I have considered it to be an integer.

These assumptions should be checked and fixed if they are not true.

Said that, notice the use of the Using Statement to correctly dispose the connection, command and reader. The removing of string concatenation from your queries is another important point. You should ALWAYS use the parameter collection to avoid Sql Injection (albeit improbable with Access) and error in parsing your values.

A final note on the order of the parameters. OleDb wants the parameter in the exact order in which the parameter placeholders appear in the query text so I have reversed the order of the INSERT to be compatible with the UPDATE command

Comment: [Usage of AddWithValue is not recommended.](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)